# close mouth for good

Tags: meaning

Two guys are arguing while third are coming to them and said to one of them:

> Why don't you shut your mouth before I close it *for good*.

It's not clear what for good emphisize here? Couldn't you explain?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40771/why-does-for-good-mean-forever

Comment: @snailboat So this is an idiom. Is that idiom and the word _forever_  replacable with each other?

Comment: Not really.  A good answer should explain how it's used.  You could also say *permanently* here, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"For good" is an idiomatic reference that means "permanently." The emphasis is intended to convey that the third party is threatening harm to one of the other speakers, eg "to close his mouth permanently" through some sort of violence or mayhem.